# Getting WPF Dispatcher from library

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

Is there a way to get the GUI Dispatcher from a library without passing reference from the GUI?

I'm working with a library (MVVM) that can invalidate datasources which will cause a GUI update. The Invalidate call needs to come from the GUI thread. I can just pass the reference, but it would be nice not to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI dispatcher for the library will be the same dispatcher for your application. Anything that needs to run on the UI thread can just be called with `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher
```